# All random variables following a distributional equation

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable

How to find out all random variables $X$ satisfying the following 2 conditions:

> $1>\ E(X^2)<\infty$
>
> $2>X$ follows the distributional equation : $X\stackrel{d}{=}{X+Y\over \sqrt2}$ for any random varibale $Y$ independent of $X$ such that $Y\stackrel{d}{=}X$

I am not getting where to begin with.

EDIT :

So , as per hints,

> Any $X$ following $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ will hold true$(\mu,\sigma^2<\infty)$, since $E(X^2)=\mu^2+\sigma^2\lt\infty$

Edit $2$: $\mu=0$ by the second equation. So $N(0,\sigma^2)$ is one candidate.

Edit $3$: Following @whuber and @dsaxton hints, we can write $$X\stackrel{d}{=}{1\over \sqrt2}\left(Y+{1\over \sqrt2}\left(Y+{1\over \sqrt2}\left(Y+\cdots\right)\right)\right)\\=Y({1\over \sqrt2}+{1\over (\sqrt2)^2}+{1\over (\sqrt2)^3}+{1\over (\sqrt2)^4}+\cdots)\\=Y(\sqrt2+1)$$

So still the question remains. Is this the only one? is there any general way to characterize all of them?

Comment: Can you think of any pair of iid random variables that satisfy this before you try to characterize all such random variables?

Comment: Hint: consider the characteristic function of the normal distribution: $\varphi(t) = e^{i \mu t + \sigma^2 t^2 / 2}$.

Comment: @Chacone Is there any general way to characterize all such distributions?

Comment: Your statement in the edit is not correct.  For one the left and right hand sides have different means.

Comment: Your second equation implies $E[X]=\sqrt{2}E[X]$, so $E[X]=0$ is a must.

Comment: @dsaxton Is it okay now? But my question still remains..

Comment: No, see @AlexR.'s comment.  Also you'd need to look at the actual distributions to show that it holds, not just the second moment of $X$.

Comment: @AlexR. Fixed. Now what?

Comment: @dsaxton Didn't understand your last sentence.

Comment: Repeat step (2) *ad infinitum* and apply the Central Limit Theorem to deduce the distribution of $X$.

Comment: @whuber Can you please expain better?

Comment: If I provided any more explanation it would be a complete solution!

Comment: @whuber I am a beginner and a student ,Sir. It will profit me to learn by examples, especially, how to handle such weird situations. It will be very grateful of you if you provide a detailed answer.

Comment: My hint may have been misleading.  The idea behind @whuber's hint is you can keep substituting i.i.d. copies of $(X + Y) / \sqrt{2}$ wherever you see $X$ or $Y$ on the right hand side.  Then notice the pattern and write a formula involving $n$ random variables on the right hand side.

Comment: @whuber I dont understand where to apply CLT. I edited my question, but I dont think I did everything in edit $3$ correctly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be more explicit and following @whuber's hint if $X \stackrel{\text{d}}{=} (X_1 + X_2) / \sqrt{2}$ where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are i.i.d. copies of $X$ then we can do another substitution in for both $X_1$ and $X_2$ and end up with (I'm reusing subscripts here so the notation doesn't get messy, but this shouldn't be confusing)

$$
X \stackrel{\text{d}}{=} \frac{X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + X_4}{\sqrt{4}} .
$$

Iterate a second time and we have

$$
X \stackrel{\text{d}}{=} \frac{X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + X_4 + X_5 + X_6 + X_7 + X_8}{\sqrt{8}} 
$$

and if we generalize this we get

$$
X \stackrel{\text{d}}{=} \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2^n} X_i}{\sqrt{2^n}} .
$$

Now what happens to the right hand side when $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Okay. So $X\stackrel{d}{=}N(0,\sigma^2)$ . But what was the necessity of $E(X^2)<\infty$ ?

Comment: The CLT doesn't apply to variables with infinite variances. Dropping the finiteness assumption would therefore complicate the solution.

Comment: @whuber Oh. I forgot that! My bad.. Anyways thanks..